# pointers and const variable

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *const plz;
```

means that I will not change where the pointer is pointing to, (ie increment or decrement the address)

```
const int *plz
```

means I will not change the variable the pointer is pointing to through the pointer

```
const int* const *plz
```

means both

I got a question

I just saw a function which looks like this

```
check_plz(const int *const plz)
```

what exactly does this mean, other than that the address cannot be incremented or decremented, if it also means that I cannot change the variable, why is the second * operand missing?
Thank you

Comment: `const int* const *plz` is a double pointer and `const int *const plz` is a single pointer. So these are very different indeed. `const int* const *plz` is the odd one out. You need to count the number of asterisks.

Comment: `http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/c-constant-pointers/` refer this

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Comment: @Dodu no that is not the same question, I also saw that question

Comment: Oh, alright. My bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const int *const plz
```

Here `plz` is a constant pointer to a constant `int` variable

The below example might help you

`const int *const *plz`

Here `plz` is a double pointer so it can hold the address of a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int a=10;
    const int *const p = &a;
    const int *const *q = &p; 
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    printf("%p\n",(void *)p);
    printf("%p\n",(void *)*q);
    printf("%d\n",**q);

    return 0;
}
```

So with this each of your used variables like `p` `q` `a` are just read-only now.

Comment: so const int *const *ptr is a constant pointer to a variable but it is not allowed that we change the variable through the pointer. Const int const *ptr is a constant pointer to a constant variable

Comment: Does one *really* need to use `const` with such gay abandon as in the examples above. We are writing in C, not C++. I cannot remember a time in the last 30 years when a `const` keyword would have saved me some debugging time, whereas overuse of `const` by others has caused much anquish (and occasionally `#define const`) to sort out problems.

Comment: @DirkKoopman Yes coming to the usage of it I agree . But for understanding the above example is good IMO